# (Fedora 34) Error "bash: java: command not found" when java is already installed

Tags: fedora

After running 'sudo dnf instal java-latest-openjdk.x86_64' and successfully installing the latest java version in Fedora 34, after I ran java --version to confirm the installation it says **bash: java: command not found** and always requests to Install package 'java-11-openjdk-headless'

Comment: Hopefully the main java package `java-latest-openjdk-headless` also got installed as dependency? ... Please check java with `sudo /sbin/alternatives --config java` ..... and `rpm -qa java-latest-openjdk-headless` .

Answer (score 0):

Try install OpenJDK 11, and Java 11:

```
sudo dnf install java-11-openjdk.x86_64
```

And, reboot your system.

If don't working, try:

```
find / -name 'java'
```

And try search the java file executable.